# What is fit_generator doing with a sub-sample of training and validation data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using a data generator with fit_generator in keras (for both training and validation data).
I was getting unexpected results so I instrumented the generator to output the batch index and count the number of steps since the last epoch.  I have added ['acc'] to the model metrics.

When fit_generator runs I see it do several things:

1. It queues up the validation data (but I'm guessing it doesn't evaluate yet).
2. It iterates through all the training data and calls on_epoch_end()
3. It calls another 10 steps of training data. I assume this must be coming from a callback.  What is it doing?
4. It completes iterating through the validation data and calls on_epoch_end()
5. It calls another 10 steps of validation data. Again, what is it doing?
6. fit_generator prints train/validation loss and accuracy and returns.

on_epoch_end() is never called after the 10 steps at 3 and 5. This is probably a bug, since we need the generators to be reset before the next epoch.

I'm mainly interested to understand what is going on at 3 and 5- why are the generators called, and why for only ten steps?

```
Versions:
print(keras.__version__)
2.2.2

print(tf.__version__)
1.9.0
```

Comment: Its not a bug, by default keras uses caching of the generator outputs, so they are being called in a different thread, so the generator and the training loop run in parallel to each other. That's what you are seeing.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it's pre-queuing data for the next epoch. However, when the next epoch runs I see that the generator is called len(generator) times.  So the generator ends up being called N+10 times before on_epoch_end is called again.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, are you using the Sequence class? Its the only way to make sure race conditions in parallel code don't happen in Keras. Without it then there can be duplicate batches.

Comment: I'm using Sequence but let me validate my claims. :-)  I have multiprocessing=False, and I have workers set to 1.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue here is that I'm calling fit_generator independently for each epoch, so I can evaluate early stopping metrics.  I need to reset the generators before calling fit_generator again.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments from Matias: the additional batches correspond to pre-queued batches for the next epoch.  They are dropped on the floor when fit_generator returns.  It's up to the user to reset the generators before calling fit_generator again.